# sqlite select request does not fetch moz_place

Tags: firefox, sqlite

I am trying to fetch historics data of the day and to print it.
the error i am getting is :

## sqlite3 : Operational error near "(" : syntax error

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import sys
import time

conn = sqlite.connect('places.sqlite.db')
c = conn.cursor()

today = str(time.time())
```

## here i am selecting the 10 first caracter because i want to search for a unix epoch match in seconds and not in milliseconds ( so only the first 10 are interesting to me)

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM moz_places WHERE LEFT(last_visit_date, 10)='"+today+"'")

user1 = c.fetchone()
print(user1)
```

### As mentionned earlier, i get "sqlite3 : Operational error near "(" : syntax error"

Do you what is wrong there ?

Comment: And are you using an extension module that provides a `left()` function? That's not a built in one.

Comment: Thanks Shawn! Do you know where to find the extension that provides a left function? Or another similar function with the same effect?

Comment: maybe substr()?

Comment: I changed it to substr, but i now get an other operational error saying that moz_places does not exist.  c.execute("SELECT * FROM moz_places WHERE substr(last_visit_date, 0, 10)>='"+today+"'")

Comment: You should use a table that exists in your database (and re-read the documentation for `substr()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to convert `moz_places.last_update_time` into a string, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS':

UTC: `datetime(last_visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch')`
Local time zone: `datetime(last_visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch','localtime')`

Here is a link to [SQLite doc on Date and Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

The `today` string created in python should match format exactly (because it will be doing a `string` comparison).

From the comments: the name of the places database in Firefox is `places.sqlite` (not `places.sqlite.db`). The database name should include full or relative path if it is not in your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks DinoCoderSaurus! I tried to upvote your answer but do not have enough reputation yet to make it work. I still have one difficulty; i read but i don't know how to use it inside the statement. Should i go this way : c.execute("SELECT * FROM moz_places WHERE last_visit_date/100000>='"+yesterday+"'")

Comment: Since python time.time() returns a float  you don't want to (shouldn't?) cast it as a string, and then this sql *should* work. plus or minus a significant digit :)

Comment: exactly, thank you so much; now it works! thank you. I am working on the next step, urlparsing of the all list of url. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. And remember you always have enough reputation to _accept_ an answer :)